# Why supervisor faild to start the program?

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue, supervisord

I am working with laravel queue jobs with Redis and using supervisor to manage multiple workers.
I have more than one numprocs which working perfectly for some days and then the supervisor **goes down** even if the supervisor in **active state**.

Because in supervisor, when supervisord fails more than `startretries` value set in configure file to start program/worker then the program/worker goes to **FATAL STATE** then it will not processing any jobs, So when all workers gone on this state the supervisor goes down.
Then we need to restart the Supervisor manually to start processing again.

But this is not a proper solution for this.
My question is why supervisor fail to start and what is the solution for that ?
Reference Supervisor Doc:-http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html
My **config file** like this:-

```
[program:name]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path/artisan queue:work --queue=queue1,queue2,queue3,queue4,default --tries=1 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=15
numprocs=150
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/path/workerError.log
```

**Update**
My log file look like this
[image]

My stdout log file looks like this

[image]
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show you supervisor log files?

Comment: Hi @Pavel I updated my question with log file data. Have a look.

Comment: Well, difficult question, the only idea is to check the moment of failing: maybe the some problems with memory, or something else. So try to see other logs(nginx, php, and so on). Also maybe it's not a good idea, but you can try to increase `startretries` param.

Comment: we can not just increase the `startretries` value, we need to find out why it is failing to start the workers.

Comment: You need to add the logs that are created through the PHP process. The current logs only show that worker 106 produced some serious problem and was shut down. 
The exciting logs should be in `worker.log` or `workerError.log`.
It could be everything from 'too many connections' in MySQL to something completely different. You may also have a look at your `/var/log/daemon.log`, as it will contain Fatal Errors inside your PHP process which is run by the workers.

Comment: `stdout_logfile=/path/worker.log`
`stderr_logfile=/path/workerError.log`

did you check these files?  do these paths exist?

Comment: @0kay I have update the question with worker logs and I don't have workerError log till now.

Comment: What happens when you run the cmd on the servers command line manually?  `php /path/artisan queue:work --queue=queue1,queue2,queue3,queue4,default --tries=1`

Comment: It execute my jobs and give me desired out put with out fail

Comment: If you run `sudo su` then `cd` to your project folder and run `php /path/artisan queue:work --queue=queue1,queue2,queue3,queue4,default --tries=1` what happens?

Comment: @Jamesking56 it will process the job present in the queue

Answer (score 1):

The relevant log entries are:

```
 exited: laravelw_106 (exit status 0; not expected)
gave up: laravelw_106 entered FATAL state, ntoo many start retries too quickly
```

The laravel queue worker stops immediately for some reason after being started.
The queue worker is supposed to be long-running.

You need to find out why it exits; maybe you have an `exit()` or `die()` statement somewhere in your jobs.

Comment: thanks for respond but in my job I don't have any `die()` or `exit()`, the job only `return()` the result on completion of task.

Answer (score 1):

Your consumers / workers die very soon after they are being started. A consumer should be a process that is running in a infinite loop waiting for tasks/messages. You said you have a return() after the task is completed, maybe this is stopping the worker.

Try to run manually the worker and then produce messages on the queue. The worker should not stop after the completion of only 1 task.

Comment: Hi @bogdancep, when I run the worker manually it is run perfectly but i am only returning result to the job handler from my user define function but I am not returning any thing from job handler method. So I am not stopping the worker after completing one task in my code.